# Method Call Expected

Tags: java

So I have an assignment where I have to create a Matrix and I have a method that is supposed to return the row in which a char appears. I'm told to throw an IllegalArgumentException if the char is not found in the matrix, but whenever I try to do so, it says Method Call Expected. Why is this?

```
public int findRow(char c) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        for(int r = 0; r < getKeyTable().length; r++)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col < getKeyTable()[r].length; col++)
            {
                if(getKeyTable()[r][col] == c)
                    return r;
            }
        }
        return throw IllegalArgumentException("uh oh");
    }
```

Comment: `throw new IllegalArgumentException("uh oh");`, not `return throw IllegalArgumentException("uh on");`

Comment: remove `return` keyword.

Comment: Why do I have to call `throw new` and not just `throw`?

Comment: `IllegalArgumentException` is a class, and you need to throw a new instance of that class.

Answer (score 4):

`return throw` isn't a thing. Either you `return`, or you `throw`.

Additionally, you need `new` to show that you want to create an instance of the `IllegalArgumentException` class, rather than invoke some method called `IllegalArgumentException` (which would be allowed, but inadvisable):

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("uh oh");
```

`return` either appears by itself (`return;`, in a `void` method), or it takes an expression (`return something;`, in a non-`void` method). `throw something` isn't an expression, so it can't appear in a return statement.

Comment: After removing `return` it still says Method Call Expected

Comment: throw **new** IllegalArgumentException

Answer (score 1):

Throwing exeptions works a little bit different:

1. Exceptions are just Objects and like every other Object, you need to instantiate them with `new`, for example:

   `new IllegalArgumentException("something really bad happened")`
2. You can throw that Throwable Object:

   `throw new IllegalArgumentException("something really bad happened")`